# Is this assigning a function to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

In the Codecademy Dice Game, I want to understand this part: `guess = get_user_guess()`, what does it mean? Turn function to a variable?

```py
from random import randint
from time import sleep


def get_user_guess():
  guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))

  return guess

def get_user_guess():
 guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))

 return guess

def roll_dice(number_of_sides):

     first_roll = randint(1, number_of_sides)
     second_roll = randint(1, number_of_sides)
     max_val = number_of_sides * 2
     print('%d is the max roll' % max_val)
     guess = get_user_guess()
     if guess > max_val:
         print("INVALID : Not supposed to roll greater than maximum rolls")
     else:
         print("Rolling...")
         sleep(2)
```

Comment: Using `()` **calls** the function. So in that case `guess` will hold the value returned by that function. If you just assign a function's name, then yes it will assign the functino object itself

Answer (score 0):

`get_user_guess` is a function that [*return*s](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/) an int value from the user's input.

In that code, `guess` will equal whatever the input is, so if I enter 10, your condition below will equate to

```py
if 10 > max_val
```

Therefore, you're not assigning the function to the variable, you're assigning the result of the function to the variable.

It is possible to assign a function to a variable, like so

```py
def test():
    return "OK"

myFunct = test

print(myFunct())
```

Prints `OK`